# iMessage App Expanded View Programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, segue, imessage, imessage-extension

I have the code below to handle the resizing when the user taps on the arrow in my iMessage app to transition to the expanded view, but how can I open the expanded view programmatically when the user segues to a new view controller in my iMessage app?

```
override func didTransition(to presentationStyle: MSMessagesAppPresentationStyle) {
    // Called after the extension transitions to a new presentation style.

    if presentationStyle == MSMessagesAppPresentationStyle.compact {
        //Resize Views
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your problem resolved?

Comment: Yes. I have accepted your answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming that you are calling this in `MessagesViewController`, you can programatically open the expanded view in the following way:

**Swift version:**

```
if self.presentationStyle == MSMessagesAppPresentationStyle.compact {
    self.requestPresentationStyle(MSMessagesAppPresentationStyle.expanded)
}
```

**Obj-C version:**

```
if (self.presentationStyle == MSMessagesAppPresentationStyleCompact) {
    [self requestPresentationStyle:MSMessagesAppPresentationStyleExpanded];
}
```